# Проблема с открытием собственного сайта в браузере Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Имеется файл сброса стилей reset.css.
В остальных браузерах сайт открывается нормально, то есть в полном масштабе, как на компьютере, так и на телефоне.
Именно браузер Google Chrome открывает криво сайт, даже не открывает его в полном масштабе.
Можете пожалуйста помочь, что стоит сделать в данной ситуации?

[image: Так должен отображаться сайт на любых устройствах]

[image: Так он отображается в Google Chrome на телефоне]

Домен сайта: trubotorg32.ru

Comment: Открыть инструменты разработчика и изучить, что и почему браузер решил отобразить криво

Comment: Что я там должен увидеть? У меня на пк начало открываться всё нормально.

Comment: А именно с телефона, и именно с хрома сайт сжимается, как в версии для пк, так и обычной.

Comment: Значит подключить телефон к компьютеру, открыть телефонные инструменты разработчика и изучить, что и почему телефон решил отобразить криво

Comment: Таким образом я уже пробовал, ничего не выходит.

Comment: Попробуйте ещё раз, может выйдет. Без знания вашей конкретной проблемы это всё, чем мы в состоянии помочь

Comment: Добавил деталий в вопрос. Можете посмотреть?

Comment: Неинформативные скриншоты без возможности потыкать [mcve] не способствуют помощи

Comment: Домен сайта: trubotorg32.ru

Comment: [mcve] должен быть предоставлен прямо в тесте вопроса без ссылок на сторонние ресурсы

Comment: Кроме того, в моём хроме этот сайт отображается нормально из-за прописанного `min-width: 1900px`. Убедитесь, что вы не забыли почистить кэш на своём телефоне

Comment: Вроде и правда работает, благодарю!